# Proving $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim _{ x\rightarrow a}g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose there is a $\delta > 0 $ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ when $0 < | x-a| < \delta$

Prove: $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$$

I defined each limit like this: $0 < | x-a| < \delta _1$ then $|f(x)-L|< \frac{|L-m|}{2}$ and for the second limit I set $0 < | x-a| < \delta _2$ then $|g(x)-m|< \frac{|L-m|}{2}$

Then I set $\delta = \min\{ \delta _1 , \delta _2 \}$ and next I did:

$$|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-m| = |f(x)-g(x)+L-m|< |L-m|$$

I'm not really sure on where to go from here, if we called $g(x)=f(x)$ (because of the small difference lemma), we would have a contradiction on our hands, any *hints* are appreciated.

There's a chance I'm over complicating the problem. So please, I'm not asking for someone to give me an answer, I think I just need a hint to get me moving forward.

Comment: Fixed, I put that in the wrong spot, sorry.

Comment: Note that the result is not precisely correct. Let $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is rational, and $1$ when $x$ is irrational. Let $g(x)=f(x)$. Then tour condition holds, but neither limit exists.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: You pointed out the subtle issue. Ideally the question should be modified that if one of the limit exists then the other also exists and has same value.

Comment: @Astrum: The result is a trivial application of the definition of limits. Since both $f, g$ are equal in a deleted neighborhood of $x = a$ their behavior is same as $x \to a$. If you wish for $\epsilon, \delta$ then let $L = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$. Now given any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1}$. Let $\delta_{2} = \min(\delta, \delta_{1})$ then we have $f(x) = g(x)$ for $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2}$ and hence $|g(x) - L| = |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2}$. This means that $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = L$

Comment: By the way my last comment uses exactly the maximum number of characters allowed in a comment. I wonder how that happened.

Comment: Magic, it's magic! Yeah, thanks. It's interesting to see that a lot of these epsilon delta proofs end up being trivial applications of the definition.

Comment: @Astrum: Many $\epsilon, \delta$ questions (at least the easy ones) are given just to give the student a feel of "real-analysis" compared to the usual feel of calculus. Deep down these epsilon, delta questions boil down to figuring out some sort of order relation (inequalities) between various numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove it using the fact that $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) - \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \lim _{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)-g(x)) =0$.

Comment: But that makes the proof trivial. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)-g(x)]=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)-\lim _{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = L-m = 0$ therefore $L=m$. 

Is this really all the question is looking for?

Comment: And this also means that I was essentially going around in circles with my posted attempt?

Comment: Yes, the only proof you may need, if it is not been proven yet is that $ \lim _{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)-g(x)) = \lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) - \lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$, and the rest follows, just try to work the $f(x)=g(x)$ when $0<|x-a|<\delta$ nicely in the proof.

Comment: And remember you got $|L-m| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. So it follows here that L=M.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The proof for $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} [f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) + \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ was already given.